# Why does Lyra-a have two belly buttons?

Tags: gene-roddenberry, genesis-ii

In the 1973 TV movie *[Genesis II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_II_%28film%29)*, Lyra-a, a Tyranian (a mutant played by Mariette Hartley), shows Dylan Hunt her belly buttons. Did Gene Roddenberry provide an in-universe explanation as to what causes Tyranians to end up with dual circulatory systems and two belly buttons? Science, radiation, or?

[image: Lyra-a showing her 2 belly buttons]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of universe explanation:

Gene Roddenberry gave her two belly buttons to spite the censors who forbid bellybuttons from being shown on network TV at the time TOS was filming.

> (In a humorous reference to the fact that Hartley was forbidden by the network censors to show her belly button on *Star Trek*, Roddenberry gave her two belly buttons for *Genesis II*.)
>
> <sub>[Memory Alpha, Mariette Hartley](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mariette_Hartley)</sub>

Comment: One is bad bad, two are good? Why do they still wear tops then? Or... wait... does that explain that Total Recall mutant with 3... as well?

Comment: The Total Recall mutant is explained by the fact that Paul Verhoeven has the sense of humour of a 12 year old boy.

Comment: I had always read this but I recently watched the Space Hippies episode and Chekov's former girlfriend is shamelessly flaunting her navel throughout.

Comment: Nice answer, and I upvoted it, but I am surprised this was marked as the official answer because the question asked about an **in-universe** explanation.

Comment: Not only the "Space Hippies episode" ("The Way to Eden", actually), but also Uhura in "Mirror, Mirror".

Comment: @CamelBlues - you say that like its a bad thing

Answer (score 5):

My guess (no quote, sorry):

Similar goal to early Star Trek: Make aliens distinctive behind the scenes to save budget.

- Two circulatory systems is something that sounds complex and is rather alien, yet it doesn't require any makeup on its own.
- Two belly buttons is a nice touch to still add some alien flavor to the actor without making it too expensive/complicated to apply. Plus it could be seen as kinda logical, considering there are two different circulatory systems.

Is there any reason for this: It's just evolution? Similar way you could ask why Vulcans got pointy ears (are they just some kind of space elves or just very nasty as kids?). Or why do humans have two legs, while there are animals having 4, 6 or even more?